# SQL Query Openers Fail

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

I am trying to run a query of all of our email openers that are older than 64.5. My SQL looks right but I keep getting the following "Automation failed due to system error." is this on my end or on SFMC end? Here is the query for reference. Thanks!

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, gender, state, email, age, lead_id
FROM leads l
LEFT JOIN _Open c ON c.SubscriberKey=l.lead_id
WHERE l.age >= 64.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the age in single quotes and try again.  SFMC is notorious for not providing any error checking in the UI.  You could submit a ticket and have them give you specific error details, but that's time consuming.

Verify that your target data extension is setup properly with a Primary Key and that the data types match what is being passed through this query. i.e. email is of type EmailAddress.

```
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    gender, 
    state,
    email, 
    age, 
    lead_id
FROM leads l
    LEFT JOIN _Open c ON c.SubscriberKey = l.lead_id
WHERE l.age >= ’64.5’
```